# Problem with theming form for my module setting page

Tags: theming, forms

I am trying to theming my module setting page.

My environment 
 
**version Drupal**  7 
**module name:** actionadscatalog 
**filesystem:** 
actionadscatalog 
      - actionadscatalog.info 
      - actionadscatalog.module 
      - actionadscatalog.admin.inc 
      - templates 
          -   admin 
             - actionadscatalog-admin_run_import.tpl.php

**actionadscatalog.admin.inc**

```
function actionadscatalog_admin_settings_runImport() {
$form['user_name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Your Name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#description' => t('Please enter your name.'),
);

$form['#theme'] = 'form_style';
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit')
);
return $form;
```

}

**actionadscatalog.module**

```
function actionadscatalog_theme() {
$path = drupal_get_path('module', 'actionadscatalog') . '/templates/admin';
return array(
    'actionadscatalog_admin_settings_runImport' => array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'template' => 'actionadscatalog-admin_run_import',
        'path' => $path,
    ),
);
```

}

```
function theme_form_style(&$variables){
$variables['adsru_action_in_load'] = 'hello theme';
```

}

**actionadscatalog-admin_run_import.tpl.php**

```
echo $variables['adsru_action_in_load'];
```

But I only see the form with user_name field. 
The file actionadscatalog-admin_run_import.tpl.php is not run.
What have i missed?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you haven't defined a theme registry entry called `form_style`, but you're setting the form's theme handler to a function with that name.

You just need to change your implementation of `hook_theme()` to match the function name and form theme setting you've actually defined:

```
function actionadscatalog_theme() {
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'actionadscatalog') . '/templates/admin';
  return array(
    'form_style' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'actionadscatalog-admin_run_import',
      'path' => $path,
    ),
  );        
}
```

Comment: I have changed the implementation of hook_theme as you showed. <br/>
After the actionadscatalog-admin_run_import.tpl.php was run, 
but the var $variables['adsru_action_in_load'] was not defined, <br/>
because the function theme_form_style had not run. 
Then I renamed the theme_form_style to template_preprocess_form_style and 
I saw my message "hello theme" on the page. <br/>
Now all are working as I wanted <br/>